# comparison test for uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

*Proof*: It's trivial that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ converges by the Comparison Test

Assume $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g_n$ converges uniformly to some non-negative real number; then we can use Weierstrass M-Test and concldue that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n$ converges uniformly.

Is it right? If there exists any missing step, please let me know.

Comment: As $g_n$ is summable, the sequence must go to zero. Hence $f_n$ does as well, and the M-test indeed works. I believe you got it!

Comment: @SeanRoberson  What do you mean "the sequence must go to $0$"? And why do you think the M-test applies?

Comment: @zhw $f_n$ is summable, so the limit zero. By comparison, we can choose our M-sequence as $g_n$ since it's summable.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Why does going to $0$ (pointwise, uniformly?) tell us anything in this problem? And the M-test is for bounds $|f_k|\le M_k,$ where the $M_k$ are constants and $\sum M_k <\infty.$ That's not what we're given here.

Comment: Since $\sum g_n$ is a series of functions, what sense does it make to say "Assume $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g_n$ converges uniformly to some non-negative real number"?

Answer (score 2):

Here $\sum g_n$ is a functional series so, your limit is a function. You can use the Cauchy criterion.

Let $\epsilon>0$, then exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for any $m, n\in\mathbb{N}$ if $N\leq m\leq n$ then
$$
\left|\sum_{k=m}^n f_k\right|\leq\left|\sum_{k=m}^n g_k\right|<\epsilon
$$

Then $\sum f_n$ is uniformly convergent.

Comment: You are trying to use the uniform Cauchy criterion. But you haven't stated it correctly.

Comment: @zhw. Why not??

Comment: Because it should read: There exists $N$ such that $N\le m\le n$ implies ...

Comment: @zhw. Yeah, I forgot it. Thanks